# dojo Query the first matching element

Tags: dojo

Is there a specific syntax to query the first matching element in dojo?

I am currently using:

```
require (["dojo/query"], function (query) {

    var foundNode = query (".className")[0];

});
```

Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: I don't think `dojo.query` supports `:first` like jQuery does. A more efficient way will depend entirely on your requirements and your DOM structure. Maybe this gives you a start - http://jsperf.com/dojo-query-first-of-type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the first node of the `NodeList` as a DOM node object, then I think tha's the correct way to do it.

If you want to return the first DOM node as a `NodeList`, then you can use the `first()` function of `dojo/NodeList-traverse`. This means you can use further NodeList-operations. Read more about them at the [reference guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/NodeList.html).

The example below gives the first node of the `NodeList` a yellow background:

```js
require(["dojo/query", "dojo/NodeList-traverse", "dojo/NodeList-dom", "dojo/domReady!"], function(query) {
    query(".className").first().style({
       "backgroundColor": "#FF0"
    });
});
```

I also made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/HdsW5/) to demonstrate this.